# what that chance is based on how much they love or hate Ohio State

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Some fans will have ideas about what that chance is based on how much they love or hate Ohio State.

Is the sentence normal?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand without context, but it's readable. I found the original paragraph.

Although the actual probability that the Ohio State football team will win the national championship is out there somewhere, no one knows what it is. Some fans will have ideas about what that chance is based on how much they love or hate Ohio State.